# C# scrolling a wpf view

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

I followed an example:

```
if(e.Delta > 0)
    {

        if (pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value - 2 >= pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Minimum)
            pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value -= 2;
        else
            pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value = pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Minimum;
    }
    else
    {
        if (pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value + 2 <= pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Minimum)
            pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value += 2;
        else
            pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value = pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
    }
```

But I don't have the pnlContain.VerticalScroll.Value it is not in there. 
So how can I scroll in a different way?

This is my WPF view:

```
<ScrollViewer
        CanContentScroll="True"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        Focusable="False"
        x:Name="Scrollers"
        >

        <!-- 
        The ZoomAndPanControl displays the NetworkView as its content.
        We can use the mouse to zoom and pan about the NetworkView.
        -->
        <ZoomAndPan:ZoomAndPanControl
            x:Name="zoomAndPanControl"
            ContentScale="{Binding ContentScale, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ContentOffsetX="{Binding ContentOffsetX, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ContentOffsetY="{Binding ContentOffsetY, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ContentViewportWidth="{Binding ContentViewportWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
            ContentViewportHeight="{Binding ContentViewportHeight, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
            Background="LightGray"
            Focusable="False"
            >

                <!--
                This grid specifies the size of the ZoomAndPanControl's content.
                It wraps up both the NetworkView and drag-zooming Canvas.
                -->
                <Grid
                    Width="{Binding ContentWidth}"
                    Height="{Binding ContentHeight}"
                    >

                    <!-- In this sample the NetworkView is the content displayed by the ZoomAndPanControl. -->

                    <NetworkUI:NetworkView
                        x:Name="networkControl"

                        NodesSource="{Binding Network.Nodes}"
                        ConnectionsSource="{Binding Path=Network.Connections}"


                        MouseDown="networkControl_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="networkControl_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="networkControl_MouseMove"
                        MouseWheel="networkControl_MouseWheel"
                        />

                    <!--
                    This Canvas and Border are used as a very simple way to render a drag rectangle that the user
                    uses to specify an area to zoom in on.
                    -->
                    <Canvas
                        x:Name="dragZoomCanvas"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        >
                        <Border 
                            x:Name="dragZoomBorder"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Background="Silver"
                            CornerRadius="1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            />
                    </Canvas>



                </Grid>

        </ZoomAndPan:ZoomAndPanControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

How should I modify the example to match my view?

Comment: Put it in a scroll viewer? This isn't very clear. What from the linked question doesn't work for you? BTW, we generally appreciate putting the relevant part of the link in the question itself, so we don't have to hunt it down :). Keep the link for attribution and context of course.

Comment: I'm not sure I have a good answer for you at the moment (thanks for providing the code though!) If the scroll bar isn't appearing, try setting a fixed height for your scroll viewer. I'll keep looking and let you know or answer if I see/find anything.

Comment: Well, you already have a scroll viewer. Have you tried ignoring the code with the properties and just using it? You may need to set it to a fixed height and remove the "Focusable="False"" line.